# List intersection in Django ORM how to?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say, I have two tables: all_my_friends_ids and my_facebook_friends_ids which represent two lists of my friends in database:

```
all_my_friends_ids = self.user.follows.values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

(e.g. all_my_friends_ids = [1, 4, 9, 16, 18, 20, 24, 70])

```
my_facebook_friends_ids = User.objects.filter(facebook_uid__in=my_facebook_friends_uids)
```

(e.g. my_facebook_friends_ids = [4, 16, 28, 44, 39])

I want to check if all elements of my_facebook_friends_ids list have entry in all_my_friends_ids or not, and if not - return id elements that are not in the all_my_friends_ids list (and add them later in all_my_friends_ids).

How to solve this task in Django ORM with QuerySet? I tried to extract ids and apply this function to them:

```
def sublistExists(list1, list2):
      return ''.join(map(str, list2)) in ''.join(map(str, list1))
```

but it doesn't seem the right way, especially for my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
facebook_exclusives = (User.objects
                       .filter(facebook_uid__in=my_facebook_friends_uids)
                       .exclude(facebook_uid__in=all_my_friends_ids))
```

If you want, you can offload it to your database completely, without creating a (potentially huge) intermediate list in Python:

```
facebook_exclusives = (User.objects
                       .filter(facebook_uid__in=my_facebook_friends_uids)
                       .exclude(facebook_uid__in=self.user.follows.all()))
```

Comment: I tried this also, but I need the solution in a Django ORM way. Is it possible?